# Remote Validation in ASPNET 5 MVC 6

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Can not find JsonRequestBehavior in aspnet 5

I am trying to implement remote validation demo and it seem like Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc does not contain JsonRequestBehavior enumeration.
But it does exist in System.Web.Mvc namespace in previous version of MVC

Model:

```
public class Person : Entity
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(512)]
        [Remote("IsAllowedName", 
                "Validation", 
                ErrorMessage="This name is not allowed!"
               )]
        [Display(Name = "First (and middle) name")]
        public String FirstMidName { get; set; }
```

View:

```
...
<input asp-for="FirstMidName"/>
<span asp-validation-for="FirstMidName"></span>
...
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult IsAllowedName(string FirstMidName)
{
    if (FirstMidName.ToLower() == "oleg")
    {
        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
    return Json(true);
}
```

Terminal output:

```
MacBook-Air-Anton:labefmvc antonprudkoglyad$ dnu build 
...
/Users/antonprudkoglyad/Projects/LabEFMVC/LabEFMVC/Controllers/
ValidationController.cs(20,24):
DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS0103: The name 'JsonRequestBehavior'
does not exist in the current context

Build failed.
```

Comment: Asp 5/MVC 6 is based on a [new codebase](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc). It seems that JsonRequestBehaviour has been removed from the new framework (as of beta8). Returning a Json from a controller works by default in GET requests.

Comment: I did not even find any mention about it at github

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Core RC1, [Remote] attribute is in the **Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc** namespace.
In ASP.NET Core RC2, [Remote] attribute is in the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc** namespace, I believe.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;

[Remote("IsAllowedName", "Validation", ErrorMessage="This name is not allowed!" )]
```